# Using nested type declared in a generic class within the generic interface that the class is implementing

Tags: delphi, generics, nested, generic-interface

I have a generic List-like class `tMyList<B>` with a method Each() which iterated over each element and calls anonymous procedure `tMyList<A>.enumProc` with paramenter - the current item of type `<B>`.
I want to implement the class as an Interface for easier lifetime management.

The problem is I cannot declare the Each method in the `iMyList<A>` interface, because `tMyList<A>.enumProc` type is unknown. As far as I know Interfaces does not support nested types?

Here is the code:

```
  tMyList<B> = class;

  iMyList<A> = interface
    procedure each(enumProcedure: iMyList<A>.enumProc); // ERROR - Undeclared identifier: 'enumProc'
  end;

  tMyList<B> = class(tInterfacedObject, iMyList<B>)
    type
      enumProc = reference to procedure(item: iMyList<B>);
    public
      procedure each(enumProcedure: enumProc);
  end;
```

`*` *Implementing Enumerator is not an option in this particular case*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that you can make this work is to define the procedural type outside of the implementing class. Like this:

```
type
  IMyIntf<A> = interface;

  TMyProc<A> = reference to procedure(Intf: IMyIntf<A>);

  IMyIntf<A> = interface
    procedure Foo(Proc: TMyProc<A>);
  end;

  TMyClass<A> = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyIntf<A>)
    procedure Foo(Proc: TMyProc<A>);
  end;
```